# What is the topological dinmension of $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: general-topology, dynamical-systems, dimension-theory-analysis

Initially, consider $\mathbb{R}$ endowed with a discrete topology, and discrete metric $\delta(x,y)=0 $ if $x=y$ and $\delta(x,y)=1 $ if $x\neq y$.

Next, we endowing $~~\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{Z}=\prod_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \mathbb{R}~~$ with the metric 
$$d(x,y)=\sum_{i=-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\delta(x_i,y_i)}{2^{|i|}},$$
where $x=(x_i),~  y=(y_i)\in \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{Z}$.

What is the topological dimension of  $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{Z}$?

Is $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{Z}$ a discrete topological space?

Is $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{Z}$ a separable topological space?

Please help me! Thanks.

Comment: No it isn't. Yes it is.

Comment: is 0, no it isn`t and yes it is.